# Is “tu fais” different from “vous faites”?

Tags: grammaire, vouvoiement

Let's analyse the French verb *faire*:

- [singular] *je fais*, *tu fais*, *il/elle fait*
- [plural] *nous faisons*, *vous faites*, *ils/elles font*

But, I was making an exercise, then I came across this phrase:

> Et vous? Qu'est-ce que vous faites?
>
> *And you? What do you do? (formal/referring to a lady)*

Look, it isn't plural – just the formal way. Should I use *faites* instead of *fais* to express formality? I mean, *fais* is when I'm using *tu* and *faites* is for *vous*? Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called "vouvoiement".
There is three different ways to talk to someone:

- **Tu**, *singular, second person*

  Target: You are speaking to only one person.

  Context:  You know this person. It is a friend, a member of your family or in some cases a colleague you work with (some people are not comfortable with it though). This isn't formal, but it is still polite to use *Tu* with someone you know.

  It is not polite to use *Tu* with someone you don't know.

  You may see some people which are clearly related (like husband and wife) that still talk to one another with *Vous* instead of *Tu*. This is rare and associated with an idea of aristocracy.
- **Vous (vouvoiement)**, *plural, second person*

  Target: You are speaking to only one person.

  Context: You know this person: you use *Vous* as a mark of respect. This person may be an elder, you boss, a customer etc.

  You don't know this person: this is the polite way to speak to someone you don't know.
- **Vous**, *plural, second person*

  Target: You are speaking to several people

  Context: You know these people: you use *Vous* as the plural of *Tu*. Same rules apply.

  You don't know these people: you use *Vous* as the plural of *Vous (vouvoiement)*. Same rules apply.

Answer (score 1):

Gramatically, *vous* is second person plural and you should aways conjugate in plural, but it's common in many languages to use the plural as a way of expressing respect or politeness towards a single person.

Even in the english phrase "And you? What do you do?" *you* can be plural, but as it happens, it's the same word for plural and singular in English.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.
'vous faites' can be use for plural OR to express formality to a person.
If you are talking to a person and use 'vous faites', you are showing politeness.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, a singular pronoun expects a verb in singular and a plural pronoun expects a verb in plural.

---

Off topic note:

This is the same rule as in English which used to have the very same distinction between casual singular and polite plural.

Nowadays, the "*vouvoiement*" is the only standard so you say

> And you? What do you do?

regardless of who you talk to. "**you**" is still technically a plural here.

The "*tutoiement*" is now an archaism but many centuries ago, you might have said

> And thee? What do thou dost?

Comment: The topic is not English, it's French.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Agreed, answer updated.